# Clustering algorithms for multiple features that are arrays/lists

Tags: clustering, python, tf-idf

my issue is that I want to cluster data from a specific context.
The dataset was 3 different texts that cannot be concatenated. 
Now I have the following "data-object" in Python:

It is an array with four different values (come from java, there keep calling lists arrays for the program):
- Attribute #1 is a list of ids that identify each entry in the dataset
- Attribute #2 is an array of tf-idf values. So it is an array consisting of values ranging from 0 to 1.
- Attribute #3 is an array of CountVektorize values. So the valuerange is from 0 to infinte. Based on the data shape the highest value it can get to is 1.
- Value #4 is an array of CountVektorize values. Same as in #3, but the values are completely unrelated.

So actually it is an array four different values and only the index is the connection between the values.

My issue is that I am lost in how to cluster the data.
I know I have to create some sort of distance, but how ?
I can compare various values from #1 with each other and I get e.g. a cosine distance.

But how can I get the #1, #2 and #3 in one cluster.
Issue is the values are weighted and concatenation is not a possibility.

Creation of the array is as follows:

```
idlist = getIdList(df) 
tdfidftext = vectorizerTexts(orderDF)
tfidferror = vectorizerErrors(orderDF)
tfidfhwsw = vectorizerHWSW(orderDF)
clusteringArray = [idlist,tdfidftext[0].toarray(),tfidferror[0].toarray()
,tfidfhwsw[0].toarray()]
```

Functions used defined like this:

```
 def vectorizerTexts(orderDFv):
      corpusA = []
      for i, entry in enumerate(orderDFv):
        corpusA.append(orderDFv.values[i][0].text + ' ' + orderDFv.values[i][1].text)
      tfidf  = TfidfVectorizer()
      corpusA = tfidf.fit_transform(corpusA)
      return corpusA, tfidf
```